# Thread safety of api client call

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

Lets consider following simplified code:

```
@Service
public class Runner {
    private Service service;


    public void process(){
        Thread threadA = new Thread("New Thread") {
            public void run(){
                service.process();
                }};

        Thread threadB = new Thread("New Thread") {
            public void run(){
                service.process();
                }};

        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();
    }
}

@Service
public class Service {

    private ApiClient apiClient;

    public void process(){
        ..do something..
        ResponseObject response = apiClient.callSomething();
        ..do something..
    }
}
```

ApiClient, Serivce and Runner are singleton beans created by Spring, injected via constructors. Now lets say that while threadA executes its work, callSomething() method gets a little timeout, meanwhile threadB starts to execute its work. Both threadA and threadB are waiting for return of callSomething(), then response from threadA execution returns. Is it possible, that due to this timeout, both threadA and threadB will go ahead with response for threadA request?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of your `ApiClient.callSomething()`, if it uses thread safe client internally or not.

Comment: @AndrewSokolov callSomething() is from 3rd party library. There is no information about thread safety of ApiClient. I am curious about this single corner-case - is it even possible?